# ruby: continue in same loop iteration after an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel a bit odd, as there are a number of questions a bit like this, but not close enough, or no answer.

[EDIT: I am rephrasing the question to make it clearer]

I have a loop that does a number of things, and was playing with it to see if various options would work to make things more readable, cleaner.  In the end, I messed something up and it threw and exception, which was caught with rescue.  So far so good.  I cannot, however, find any way to make ruby just continue with the following statements in that same iteration of the loop - the exception always casues the following statements and it moves on to the next iteration - default behaviour.  Redo or retry would be pointless and result in an infinite loop, hitting the same error and exception again, etc,

I there any way to force ruby to handle the error in some way then just continue where it left off?

Here is a sample, stolen from I don't know where and adapted.

```
3.times do |i|
  begin
    # first bunch of stuff to do
    # second bunch of stuff to do
    # third bunch of stuff to do
    # fourth bunch of stuff to do
  rescue => e
    p e
  end
end
```

Basically, in this example, I want all four of the bunches of stuff to be executed before moving on to the next iteration of the loop, even if one of them should cause an error.  I wasn't to process the error, allowing me to see the exception result, etc, but effectively ignoring it and continuing on to do all that other bunches of stuff.

Any ideas?  It might be something really obvious that I have just never seen before.

Comment: Should the `puts` be executed regardless of whether an exception occurred or not?

Comment: Yes.  That simulates the string manipulation and so on in the main program I was messing around with.

Comment: If you're using deliberate exceptions for flow control that's probably a mistake. Why not just an `if`?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, by the way - I was just adding the ' ' when you edited it. :)

Comment: I'm not - I want to know about the error, but I want the rest of the statements to be executed as if the error had not happened.

Comment: _"I have a loop that does a number of things"_ – maybe you should provide a more detailed example then. It's hard to give advice based on a single `begin-rescue` block within a loop :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining a `begin-end` block with a `rescue` clause. If any exception is raised by the block and there's a matching rescue clause, the block will stop executing and the rescue clause will be executed. If there's no matching rescue block, the error will bubble up (and hopefully be handled by another block, otherwise it'll be unhandled and your script will stop!) If there's an `ensure` clause, that'll get run too even if there's an exception.

So where does that leave us? If you want to defend against failure of individual steps and continue regardless, each step needs its own block:

```
3.times do |i|
  begin
    first_thing
  rescue => e
    puts "The first thing blew up! #{e.inspect}"
    puts "I'll carry on anyway ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
  end

  begin
    second_thing
    third_thing
  rescue => e
    puts "Either the second or third thing blew up... #{e.inspect}"
    puts "Straight on to the fourth thing!"
  end

  begin
    fourth_thing
  rescue => e
    puts "Fourth thing blew up! #{e.inspect}"
  end
end
```

---

It's a bit unusual to have a block like this which should carry on executing if something goes wrong - that's usually a good way to make one of the next steps go wrong too! You might need to make sure that you still have data integrity at each point, and that the later steps don't depend on something which might have failed to happen in the earlier steps.

Comment: Thanks all - I think I have my answer then.  There's nothing built-in, really, to do error handling then carry on.  Separate blocks are the way to go if I want to do this.  It's a bit clunky, but you seldom get everything in life! The basis here was reading a line from a file, after checking the network was up the file existed and could be opened and we actually got a line in, then doing a large number of independent things to it/with it, so I was comfortable with it until this error and situation, which led me down this path after about a day of wasting my time on non-working solutions.  :)

Answer (score 2):

A `begin` block (including implicit ones from say `def`) ends on the first exception. If you want to do somthing seperately after regardless of success/failure, then put it outside the block.

```
3.times do |i|
  begin
    raise "Raised from iteration #{i}"
  rescue => e
    p e
  end
  puts "I'm after the exception"
end
```

If you want to do something even after a `return`, `break`, etc. then use an `ensure` block.

```
5.times do |i|
  begin
    break if i == 3
    raise "Raised from iteration #{i}"
  rescue => e
    p e
  ensure
    puts "I always run #{i}"
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
#<RuntimeError: Raised from iteration 0>
I always run 0
#<RuntimeError: Raised from iteration 1>
I always run 1
#<RuntimeError: Raised from iteration 2>
I always run 2
I always run 3
```

If you really want to ignore and continue from many statements that might throw, they each need a seperate `rescue` block. You could do this with another wrapper method. However be very careful that the exception being ignored really do not matter than that continuing is safe.

Exception by design, are meant to abort the following operations and try to avoid leaving inconsistent and unknown program states.

```
def suppress
  yield
rescue => e
  puts "Supressing #{e}"
end
5.times do |i|
  suppress { raise "I throw sometimes #{i}" if i <= 3 }
  suppress { raise "I throw sometimes too #{i}" if i > 2 }
  puts "After possible exceptions #{i}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
Supressing I throw sometimes 0
After possible exceptions 0
Supressing I throw sometimes 1
After possible exceptions 1
Supressing I throw sometimes 2
After possible exceptions 2
Supressing I throw sometimes 3
Supressing I throw sometimes too 3
After possible exceptions 3
Supressing I throw sometimes too 4
After possible exceptions 4
```

Comment: Thanks Fire Lancer - but that works if you KNOW that a certain piece of your code might through and exception.  If you don't know, or don't know which piece, you want the rescue to wrap around all that code, so you can't necessarily do it like this.  Imagine the raise actually being a load of stuff that might, at some point, given some condition, throw an exception.

Comment: generally speaking, its not safe to continue "the next statement" after an exception, and would be difficulty, if you really want to, you need to explictly wrap them in some way, either seperate explict begin blocks, or some wrapper method

Comment: You don't want to write YOLO code that bulldozes through exceptions and just keeps going.

Comment: Note since this is tagged with ruby-on-rails, that ActiveSupport adds a [`Kernel#suppress`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-suppress) method for you, granted you don't get a `puts` statement from it